# Extracting data from JSON array and store them on a two-dimension array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

SMS messages on Android mobiles, are stored in databases, so I extracted,
and stored them in a JSON array.

I want to group the SMS by the address (mobile number).

The structure I want to create is a two-dimension array that on each first index of the second dimendsion (value 0, matrix[index][0]) is stored the number and on the other values are the sms of that number.

The error is that after storing 2 numbers, the other numbers are not getting stored and the sms received by them are stored on the second number array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var sms = {
    '0' : {
        'address' : '+1',
        'body' : 'SMS1'
    },
    '1' : {
        'address' : '+2',
        'body' : 'SMS2'
    },
    '2' : {
        'address' : '+1',
        'body' : 'SMS3'
    },
    '3' : {
        'address' : '+2',
        'body' : 'SMS4'
    },
    '4' : {
        'address' : '+3',
        'body' : 'SMS5'
    },
    '5' : {
        'address' : '+4',
        'body' : 'SMS5'
    }
};

var matrix = [];
var html = "";
var actualBODY = "";
var actualADDRESS ="";
var matrixDOneSize =0;
var matrixDTwoSize =0;
var indexOfValue =0;
var pinpoint =-10;
for(i in sms) {
   if (sms.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

 actualBODY = sms[i]['body'];
 actualADDRESS = sms[i]['address'];
 if(i==0){
  
  matrix[0]=[];
  matrix[0][0]=actualADDRESS;
  matrix[0][1]=actualBODY;
 }
 
 else {
  matrixDOneSize = matrix.length;
  
  for(var j=0;j<matrixDOneSize;j++){
   
      indexOfValue = matrix[j][0].indexOf(actualADDRESS);
       if(indexOfValue>-1){
          pinpoint = j;
          
         }
        
        }
        
        if(pinpoint>-10) {
  matrixDTwoSize = matrix[pinpoint].length;
  matrix[pinpoint][matrixDTwoSize]=actualBODY;
  }
  else {
   matrix[matrixDOneSize]=[];
   matrix[matrixDOneSize][0]=actualADDRESS;
   matrix[matrixDOneSize][1]=actualBODY;
   
  }
  
 }
 
 
 }
 
}
var nexti = matrix.length;
html+="Total numbers ="+nexti;
for(var i=0;i<nexti;i++){
html+= "<ul>Mobile Number = "+ matrix[i][0];

var nextj = matrix[i].length;
var nrsms = nextj-1;
html+= "<li>Nr of SMS= "+nrsms+"</li>";

for(var j=1;j<nextj;j++){

html+= "<li>SMS = "+ matrix[i][j]+"</li>";
}
html+="</ul>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you just want to group those items by `address` property, sum up their parent keys and collect `sms` names for each group, right?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah thats what i did :) !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i have to reset the pinpoint variable when i find 
a new sms for an existing number.

So :

```
 if(pinpoint>-10) {

  matrixDTwoSize = matrix[pinpoint].length;
  matrix[pinpoint][matrixDTwoSize]=actualBODY;
  pinpoint = -10;
  }
```